# Flutter - using an API key

Tags: json, dart, flutter, restful-authentication, restful-url

I'm making an app that grabs cryptocurrency JSON data from the [public v1 Api](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/) but support for this will soon be dropped, meaning that I'll have to migrate the the more powerful [professional v1 Api](https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/api/v1#tag/cryptocurrency).

The only issue is, I don't know how to implement the use of the new Api key thats required as I parse the JSON data.

I'm using a heavily modified version of this [git repo](https://github.com/iampawan/CryptoApp) to program the app, but all basic functionality is based here.

All I need is guidance on what I need to add to this file to display the new professional v1 Api, any comments or ideas are appreciated. Thanks

This the the `crypto_data_prod.dart` file where I would have to change my code for use with the key.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:fluttercrypto/data/crypto_data.dart';

class ProdCryptoRepository implements CryptoRepository {
  String cryptoUrl = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=50";
  @override
  Future<List<Crypto>> fetchCurrencies() async {
    // TODO: implement fetchCurrencies
    http.Response response = await http.get(cryptoUrl);
    final List responseBody = JSON.decode(response.body);
    final statusCode = response.statusCode;
    if (statusCode != 200 || responseBody == null) {
      throw new FetchDataException(
          "An error ocurred : [Status Code : $statusCode]");
    }

    return responseBody.map((c) => new Crypto.fromMap(c)).toList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change `http.Response response = await http.get(cryptoUrl);` to

`http.Response response = await http.get(cryptoUrl, 
headers: {"X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": "cab79c7b-52e9-4e4b-94fc-b0f32da14799"});`

For more info check [this link](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests/).

Comment: I'm sure this works, but it turns out that the JSON type is styled differently to the public V1 api, I'm now getting the error `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`

Comment: Hi Daniil, any luck with this?

Comment: In case anyone needs to hear the answer: The call used to return an array (aka list in dart) while it now returns a JSON Object (aka Map in dart).